# Comma semantics

Tags: math-mode, spacing, punctuation

I am wondering about whether to use text or math comma in the following cases (because they carry different spacing), and whether if style guides actually have comments on these.

- The points A, B and C are on the same line.
- `$a, b \in S$` or `$a$, $b \in S$`
- `$i = 1, 2, \dots, n$` or `$i = 1$, $2$, $\dotsc$, $n$`

Comparison for the last one:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered before, but I'm not sure what to search for.  This should be entered as appropriate for the meaning.  In both cases, the entire expression is a single math unit, and should be in a single pair of `$`.  Not long ago, there was a question that asked what to do if such an expression came at the end of a line, and it really had to be split; that would shed some additional light on this, but (as I said), I'm not sure how to search for that.  By the way, you really don't want  `\dotsc`; the dots should be on the line.

Comment: `\dotsc` specifically means dots between commas. I actually used cdots everywhere before, then realized ldots is the convention.

Comment: Urk.  You're correct; `\dotsc` is indeed "dots with commas.  (Confusing with `\cdots`.)  Thanks for correction.